# html+css Error in css float boxes with image fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have some images with original size 260px, i want to show 4 images per line in the container with max-width:1024px; so i set image width 100% and a div box container width:205px; and margin: 10px; and the error occures, what is wrong with the code below?

What happens:
[a print screen of the error][1]

The code is this:
https://www.appdevtools.com/pastebin/k3fxj5

Comment: Please post here the relevant code, tip: take a look to flexbox instead of a float ;)

Comment: If you want to display 4 images per line you may want to put those images in a div representing a line, like `<div class="line><img src=... /><img src=... /><img src=... /><img src=... /></div>` and also use flexbox as @Sfili_81 suggested

Comment: the code is here: https://pastebin.com/kpuX5BE4

Comment: if you want to show 4 images in each line, and parent width is 1024, then why you keeping the width of your div to 205? \

Comment: a print screen of the problem is here: https://prnt.sc/uvzf50

Comment: @AtulRajput  it is 930px but this is not of major importance

Comment: got your problem, as you already selected one answer as the right one, do you still need your code to be fixed with floats, althoug flex is a better approch, just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case your should use FlexBox.

Like this:

```
.clearfix {
  max-width:1024px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between:
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.linkbox {
  width: 205px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: it worked with display: flex; and flex-wrap: wrap; but i dont understand why width: 205px; property accures this error and if you delete it all works as it suposed

Comment: this implementation would be a problem in this case, for example, all images are 26, then 
6 lines of the image would be great, with 4 images in each line, but in 7th line there would be 2 images and those will be far apart from one another, and the design will not look good.

Comment: @Georgegp share the error screenshot, in your question its not there